# Error after upgrading from ethers v5.7 to v6.7

Tags: ethers.js, etherscan

With React Native 0.70.x app, upgrading from ethers v5.7 to v6.7 causes the error below:

```
error: node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js: /Users/macair/Documents/code/js/xyz_app6/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/abi-coder.js: Class private methods are not enabled. Please add `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` to your configuration.
  111 |  */
  112 | class AbiCoder {
> 113 |     #getCoder(param) {
      |     ^
  114 |         if (param.isArray()) {
  115 |             return new array_js_1.ArrayCoder(this.#getCoder(param.arrayChildren), param.arrayLength, param.name);
  116 |         }
 BUNDLE  ./index.js
```

Installed dev `"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.18.6"` and added to babel.config.js:

```
overrides: [
    {
      test: './node_modules/ethers',
      plugins: [
        ["@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
      ]
    }
  ]
```

from https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/4309. But the problem remains.